# Mysql trigger returns 1442 error

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I have testing table with `order` attribute. When `order` changes it value i need to recalculate all `order` values in table. I have the following trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `testing`$$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `UpdateOrder`$$

CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */
    TRIGGER `UpdateOrder` AFTER UPDATE ON `upd_tst` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (OLD.order > NEW.order) THEN
        UPDATE `upd_tst` t SET t.`order` = t.`order` + 1 WHERE t.`order` < OLD.order AND t.`order` >= NEW.order AND t.id <> OLD.id;
    ELSEIF (OLD.order < NEW.order) THEN
        UPDATE `upd_tst` t SET t.`order` = t.`order` - 1 WHERE t.`order` > OLD.order AND t.`order` <= NEW.order AND t.id <> OLD.id;
    END IF;
    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

When i try to update any item, i get nex error:

```
Executed SQL Statement : update `testing`.`upd_tst` set `order`='3' where `id`='3' 
Error Number : 1442 
Error Message: Can't update table 'upd_tst' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

How i can fix this problem? I need to use ONLY trigger.

In postgresql i can use this condition inside trigger `WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() = 0)`. Is there something like this in mysql?

Comment: Think about it,if you have an after update trigger for updates you`ll have an infinite loop

Comment: Either do recalculations on the fly on use another table just for recalculations

Comment: i thought that i can avoid infinite loop with this condition ` AND t.id <> OLD.id`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: Make it `BEFORE UPDATE ON` trigger - so you can set/update the field values in the trigger SQL:

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `testing`$$
DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `UpdateOrder`$$
CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */
    TRIGGER `UpdateOrder` BEFORE UPDATE ON `upd_tst` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (OLD.order > NEW.order) THEN
        SET NEW.order = NEW.order` + 1;
    ELSEIF (OLD.order < NEW.order) THEN
        SET NEW.order = NEW.order - 1;
    END IF;
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

---

**Cause**: You cannot update/delete/insert to a table where the trigger is invoked:

> Within a stored function or trigger, it is not permitted to modify a
>   table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the
>   statement that invoked the function or trigger.

Doing so will generate Error 1442:

```
Error Code: 1442
Can't update table 'MyTable' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```